# Configuring postfix in local machine in order to send mails

Tags: postfix, mail-command

I am trying to automate a procedure and when a certain condition is met I would like to notify the user with an automated mail using the **mail** command.

The thing is, that the messages are not being send and as far as I understood there are some configurations that have to be made first.

The thing is that when I go with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

in order to modify it I am not completely sure about what to fill there.

- 1 - The first page asks for System mail name
- 2 - The second one asks
  for root and postmaster mail recipients
- 3 - Other destinations to
  accept mail
- 4 - Force synchronous mail queue Y/N
- 5 - Local networks
  (this was pre-filled)
- 6 - Mailbox size
- 7 - Local address extension
  character
- 8 - Protocols (ipv6, ipv4)  `# I selected them both`

But I really need help with 1,2,3,5,7 because when i try to send a test mail I do not receive anything

Thank you in advance

Update:

#### OS info

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

#### Postfix version

```
mail_version = 3.4.10
```

#### postconf

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 100
mydestination = aoos.homenet.telecomitalia.it, aoos, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
myhostname = aoos.homenet.telecomitalia.it
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter =
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

#### mailq

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
DD866CE073F*    2566 Sun May 10 18:17:10  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

DA34ECE0693*    2493 Fri May 15 19:08:58  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

D474DCE0692*    2531 Fri May 15 19:08:58  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

CFCC4CE0690*    2491 Fri May 15 19:08:58  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

0DC1FCE0738*    2398 Sun May 10 18:05:51  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

D06F9CE0691*    2497 Fri May 15 19:08:58  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos

3534ECE068E      417 Fri May 15 17:01:06  broxigar@aoos
(host mx.<domain_name>.it[130.192.182.65] said: 452 4.5.2 Could not resolve sender domain. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
                                         userXXX@<domain_name>.it
```

### After Edit (postconf -n)

```
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

#smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
#smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
#smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
#smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
#smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = aoos.polito.it
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, aoos.polito.it, localhost.polito.it, localhost

#myorigin = $mydomain 
relayhost = [mail.polito.it]:465
#relay_domains = $mydestination
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

### After Edit (mailq)

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
64428CE10EA*    2334 Fri Jun 19 22:55:27  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         broxigar@aoos
```

### After Edit (journalctl -xe)

```
Jun 19 22:55:29 aoos postfix/smtp[1158006]: 64428CE10EA: to=<broxigar@aoos>, relay=server.domain.it[<ip_addr>]:465, delay=2, delays=0.01/0/0.03/2, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host server.domain.it[<ip_addr>] said: 551 broxigar@aoos failed to route the address (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Please, help us help you ! Edit your question with (i) your platform info. (ii) the version of postfix, we're dealing with. (iii) your current set up. You can do the latter by typing `$ postconf -n` in terminal and showing us the resulting output. Notify me (if you want) by typing my avatar in a comment below, preceded by "@". Cheers.

Comment: Also show us in your edit, what the output of `$ mailq` is in terminal.

Comment: @Cbhihe Thank you for your guidance. Here is the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

*[Disclaimer: What follows was fully tested for Postfix v3.5.1. on an up-to-date Arch linux install.  Troubleshooting for Postfix v3.4.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 should be very similar, except (maybe) for a few file paths hardcoded in `main.cf` and/or `master.cf`.]*

I see parameter settings that start with `smtpd_...`. This is only necessary if you mean your host's local postfix's setup to be able to handle **incoming** email. If you only want to **send** email via a smtp relay, you can comment those out.

***Error 452**: Could not resolve sender domain. (in reply to MAIL FROM command) userXXX@\<`domain_name`>.it*

Your local host's domain is not resolved correctly. Apparently, from your question's edit, it is not correctly set. Add the following or modify your existing config in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = ${{$compatibility_level} < {1} ? {yes} : {no}}
tls_append_default_CA = no
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost  
                                  # might speed up your sending process if your host 
                                  # is part of a subnet with other hosts.
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = aoos                   # confirm that's the local domain name you chose 
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $mydomain
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:465  # << only when using gmail as smtp server.
                                  # Replace with your own smtp  server.  Always include
                                  # square brackets as shown + optional port.
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
                                  # or use 'smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs' as shown by you
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt # Use either 'encrypt' or 'may'
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes        # Poorly or not documented, but necessary when 
                                  # using TLS with Google's smtp outgoing mail gateway
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

In addition to the above, you need to secure your username and passwd for the smtp gateway you use, in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. Below I include an example for smtp.gmail.com:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
[smtp.gmail.com]:465  <my_username>@gmail.com:<my_passwd>
$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

***EDIT #1:*** Also do: `$ sudo chown root:postfix /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd*`

I assume that you have the service `postfix` already enabled and started. If it is not enabled, do: `sudo systemctl enable postfix`.

Reload configuration parameter and restart the `postfix` service:

```
$ sudo postfix reload
$ sudo systemctl restart postfix.service
```

Finally try sending email:

```
$ touch foobar
$ mail -s "test #<my_test_nbr>" -a foobar <my_external_email> < <(echo "Hello world")
$ journalctl -xe    # report relevant warnings & errors   (***EDIT***)
$ mailq             # report full output
```

Report if you have more issues. HTH.

---

***EDIT #2:*** 
I see from your attempts at sending mail with postfix, that sending occurs over IPv6. RFC-6724 indicates that if a machine is dual-stacked (where both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols run on the same network infrastructure), a connection to IPv6 should be attempted first. You most likely have such a setup. AFAIK, Google accepts stmp requests over IPv6 but solely if the source of the request provides [reverse domain name for authentication](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/mirjam/sending-and-receiving-emails-over-ipv6) purposes. You cannot control that from MTA side; it's in the hands of your ISP.  So, if I were you, I would first try to get sending over IPv4 working and then experiment with IPv6.  For that, at least for testing purposes with gmail, change `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

It does not mean you are stuck with IPv4 for all your IP connectivity. There is a `postfix` work-around with `transport` maps if you still want IPv6, with the exception of gmail; a different question you want to ask in a different post perhaps.

Comment: HEllo again! THank you for your assistance. I tried modifying the file and also I created a **sasl_passwd** file in the /etc/postfix/ directory that includes my personal e-mail information. But after trying to send an e-mail the e-mail was not sent. I have edited my original post with further information (if that helps you)

Comment: @Broxigar: please **1)** place the exact command you issued to send email above the `mailq` output section in your post; **2)** in `/etc/postfixmain.cf`, try replacing `smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs` with `smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Make sure that latter file does exist and is up to date on your system. **3)** can you tell us the output of (a) `$ hostname` and of (b) `$ more /etc/hosts | grep -v -e "^#'` (without the commented lines) ?  **4)** log in into google web-mail and make sure that your gmail account does accept connections from "less secure apps".

Comment: @Broxigar: **5)** after any change to either `main.cf` or `master.cf` do not forget to do: `$ sudo postfix reload; $ sudo systemctl restart postfix.service`. **6)** always stick to the same mail sending test. **7)** After sending email always look at `$ mailq`  and also at `$ journalctl -xe` to be able to report relevant errors and warnings.  It's a process... **8)** Did you modify the default settings in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` in any way ?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Here is the requested information. I tried again after changing what you suggested.

Comment: I configured the postfix somehow. I am able to send a message and the mailq is empty after sending the message. But still I am not receiving it! After inspecting the ```journalctl -xe``` I see the following message **host x.y.z said: 573 user@machine failed to route the address (in reply to MAIL FROM command)** . @Cbhihe

Comment: @Broxigar: not sure where you are at in this troubleshooting process. Usually things are not that protracted. But in order to get closure on this: **(a)** show a link in a comment below with the content of yr new `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file; **(b)** if you send a message and the message **is** sent, then `mailq` should return "empty".  So the most obvious question is: **(c)** where do you send that mail message ?

Comment: I have moved the machine from my home network to the workspace. So I "copied" the```main.cf ``` file from another machine that had postfix configured. I am updating the post with the latest file.

Comment: Should I post something more? @Cbhihe